# Can anyone suggest a way to create an integer key out of a class?

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash

I am new to computer science and I guess this has something to do with hash function.

I have a class in cpp:

```
class Car{
    public:
    int fleetId;
    OwnershipEnum owner;
    int buildDate;
    bool hasFourDoors;

    ... with many other members
};
```

Now, my problem is, how to 'scientifically' generate an integer key based on the 4 members I list?

I can think of a simple way, `10000*int(fleetId) + 1000 * int(owner) + 100×int(buildDate) + int(hasFourDoors)`

I think ideally the key is continuous, so I can store all the Car objects in an array and use this generated key to DIRECTLY access the car object.

***** as per the comments: the cars are all different, there is no identical cars ********

***** these four members are static: they won't change after being created *****

Can anyone point me to the right solution here?

Thanks

Comment: Can two different `Car` instances share the same key?

Comment: You can't generally ensure that all the keys will be different, unless the range of values of each field is small. You have to allow for hash collisions.

Comment: The purpose of a key is to uniquely identify an object. That means that `isGoodCondition` and `isBooked` aren't suitable for inclusion in a key, because these values will change over time. For a car, something like its registration plate and registration date should be sufficient to identify it.

Comment: " ideally the key is continuous, so I can store all the Car objects" does that means there will be only one car array, and the array is constant array?

Comment: Those fields still don't look unique. I'm not sure you can have a unique key without at least two of the fields having mutually exclusive values for every single car produced or else one value that is exclusive (unique) to every car.  Like a registration number/chassis number/engine number etc...

Comment: if each car is different and they don't change place in memory then you can just use pointers

Answer (score 3):

You can build a method to get it, using `std::hash`:
Its just an easy example.

```
std::size_t CarHash(const Car& car)
{
    std::size_t h1 = std::hash<int>{}(car.fleetId);
    std::size_t h2 = std::hash<int>{}(int(car.owner));
    std::size_t h3 = std::hash<int>{}(int(car.isGoodCondition));
    std::size_t h4 = std::hash<int>{}(int(car.isBooked));
    return h1^(h2 << 1)^(h3 << 2)^(h4 << 3);
}
```

Comment: Minor question: do you think it would be sufficient to use just the address of the object, since they should be unique?

Comment: `std::hash<Car>{}(int(car));` can you explain this?

Comment: @yassin nope, it has no explanation (because it was wrong), I just fixed it, thank you for pointing it :)

Comment: @DanielSanchez this would also need a type conversion function right?

Comment: @yassin, yes, but since he provided that code on his example i pressume he already has that. EDIT:actually i missread, im updating again.

Answer (score 3):

The combination of these members is not enough to uniquely identify a car: Imagine two cars having the same fleetId (because of being part of the same fleet), the same owner, and both being booked and in good condition. This would result in the same id if you calculate it based on these properties. As suggested by @jsheeran, you can use the license plate as an unique identifier.

Otherwise, add another member for id to your car class and have a static variable for a global, increasing key on every constructor call of car. However, be aware that this is only a sample implementation and you might want to have another class for managing the keys, because this implementation will never "free" keys.

```
class Car{

public:
    Car() : id(++nextId) {}

    const unsigned id;

private:
    static unsigned nextId;
};

unsigned Car::nextId = 0U; // initialize in your cpp using the cars

int main()
{
    Car a;
    Car b;
    Car c;

    std::cout << a.id << b.id << c.id; // will print 012
}
```

Another suggestion would be to use GUIDs. Depending on your platform or used libraries, you can find a solution here for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Let assume you want a key without collision and all field can take any value in their range, you'd have to use a sizeof(int) + sizeof(OwnershipEnum) + 2 bits key to prevent all collisions, or 66 bits. It can be considered acceptable and computed like this:

```
struct key {
    int fleetId;
    OwnershipEnum owner;
    char bools;

    key(Car _myCar) : 
        fleetId(_myCar.fleetId), 
        owner(_myCar.owner), 
        bools(!!_myCar.isGoodCondition & !!_myCar.isBooked << 1 ) 
    {}

    bool operator ==(key other) { return fleetId == other.fleetId && owner == other.owner && bools == other.bools; }
};
```

then test like this:

```
  Car first{1, (OwnershipEnum)2, false, true};
  Car second{1, (OwnershipEnum)2, false, true};
  Car third{8, (OwnershipEnum)1, true, true};

  key k1{first}, k2{second}, k3{third};

  std::cout << (k1 == k2) << "\n"; //true
  std::cout << (k2 == k3) << "\n"; //false
  std::cout << (k3 == k1) << "\n"; //false
```

full example program: http://cpp.sh/2vv2a

It's obviously a wrong assumption but you can try to reduce the key size if you can make all possible value for fleetId fit in 16 bits or shorten OwnershipEnum as for example